# How can I capture messages that occur at shutdown?

Tags: shutdown, logs

When I shut down Ubuntu 14.04, messages appear on a black screen but go away before I can read them.  How can I capture these messages, or what log file can I check to find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the directory /var/log and see if it is in one of the subdirs or as a .log file

Comment: Thanks.  I am looking there now.  I ran a command to find all the log files  find . -iname  '*.log'  but it returned massive results, so I narrowed it to find /var -iname  '*.log' and I'm looking at those now.  The message at shutdown goes by so fast that I couldn't even pick out one word, so I'm not sure what I'm looking for.

Comment: If I was at home I would have found the auction file name but I am on my phone so sorry for that inconvenience

Comment: I think I may have found it in /var/log/syslog.   I will bounce the system again and see if it occurs again with current timestamp in the log.  Then I will know what is going on.  Thanks for the clues.